# iOS animated textView returns to original position when imagePicker is presented?

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit

I think I'm probably missing something obvious here?

I have a UITextView that I animate it's y position when a user takes a certain action via

```
CGRect frame = self.messageTextView.frame;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

frame.origin.y += 120;
self.messageTextView.frame = frame;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

That works great, but when my user taps a button to launch an imagePicker that animated UITextView snaps back to its original position as the imagePicker launches so, when the imagePicker is dismissed, my UITextView is in an unexpected place (where it began, not where it was animated to). Why is that? And how can I get it to retain its new position?

thanks!

Comment: Are you setting the original frame of the text view in viewWillAppear or anything like that?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my own problem by unchecking "Use Autolayout" on the UITextView. The autolayout constraint was snapping the view back to its starting place :\